# Load PDF file in webview

Tags: android, pdf, webview

I am having webview in my app, i am loading website in my webview and in that website there are multiple links of PDF file but while i am clicking on that it is not opening in webview,
if i am checking it in my windows's browser it opening.
i have enabled javascript but no luck, i used following properties also

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
```

Comment: android webview doesnot support pdf content, You may use google docviewr to show your pdf file

Comment: try to implement using thirdparty library like mupdf and all as in android webview doesn't support pdf and google docviewer hv sme limit like after opening pdf for some number of time. it will gve bandwith message where u cnt view pdf even in google doc

Comment: You can find my answer here
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36979733/load-pdf-file-on-webview-with-okhttp-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36979733/load-pdf-file-on-webview-with-okhttp-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android does not work like iOS in this respect. The WebView widget cannot display PDF documents on Android.

You will have to:

- Use a third party library (unfortunately, most open source pdf libs are GPL)
- Open a pdf viewer app via an Intent
- Use Google docs in a webview

Answer (score 1):

this may help you,

```
String myPdfUrl = "http://example.com/awesome.pdf";
String url = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + myPdfUrl;
Log.i(TAG, "Opening PDF: " + url);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Use https at the place of http.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to open pdf saved in google drive this code can be used

```
     WebView view=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
     view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
     String url=getIntent().toString("value1");
     String URL="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url="+url; 
     view.loadUrl(Url);
```

Comment: this opens in google doc , i want to open within webview

Comment: This open the google docs inside your activity. Please define the webview inside your activity.  view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); add this line to code. if still does not work. Please post your code.

Comment: what do you mean by view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); Do you know why webviewclient is used in webview.

Comment: When the user clicks a link from a web page in your WebView, the default behavior is for Android to launch an application that handles URLs. Usually, the default web browser opens and loads the destination URL. However, you can override this behavior for your WebView, so links open within your WebView.  This is the use of WebViewClient()

Comment: Let me know it worked for you or not and also rank me if it helped you :)

Comment: thanks mate :), I just need this --       String URL="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url="+url;  It solves my problem.