# Download pdf file direct in android WebView

Tags: android, pdf, webview

I'm developing a webview application in android. In chrome or other browser when i click on any link which has link to pdf file will be open in new tab or download the file. But in android webview when i click on that link there is nothing happen.
Here is my code...

```
package aneridevelopers.com.govtofgaurang;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String WebAddress = "http://www.govtofgaurang.com/";
String url = WebAddress;
String loadUrl = WebAddress;
private WebView webView;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private FrameLayout frameLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setMax(100);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new HelpClient());

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress){
            frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.setProgress(progress);

            setTitle("Loading...");

            if(progress == 100){
                frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                setTitle(view.getTitle());
            }
            super.onProgressChanged(view, progress);
        }
    });

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.loadUrl(WebAddress);
    progressBar.setProgress(0);
}
private class HelpClient extends WebViewClient{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

Please help me... I'm new in Android.

Comment: When you are returning `true` in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` then you need to do something with that url, webview will not do anything. In your case, you need to pass that link to `download manager` or something similar to get your file downloaded.

Comment: Can you please write here code for me?

Comment: A search on google get me this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28518373/6383029

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load PDF file in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813218/load-pdf-file-in-webview)

Comment: PDF file will open in new tab and webview does not support new tab function.

Comment: Ehhh. WebView does not support displaying pdf files to begin with.

Comment: That's why i need to download pdf...